# sort dict by key list

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have this:

```
order = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'baz',
]
data = {
    'bar': 'barValue',
    'foo': 'fooValue',
    'baz': 'bazValue',
}
```

I want in the end to have this:

```
sorted_data = [
    'fooValue',
    'barValue',
    'bazValue',
]
```

So, I have a dict with key-value pairs and I have a list which contains keys from that dict in some order. I want to get a list of dict values sorted by keys in the order they are specified in the list.

I need this because unfortunately Django doesn't support something as simple as this in templates:

```
{% for key in order %}
    <div>{{ data[key] }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is not called `sorting`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a very simple one-liner here and it goes like this

**Python 2.7 version**

```
>>> map(data.get, order)
['fooValue', 'barValue', 'bazValue']
```

**Python 3.x version**

```
>>> list(map(data.get, order))
['fooValue', 'barValue', 'bazValue']
```

Answer (score 6):

Try with list comprehension:

```
sorted_data = [data[a_data] for a_data in order]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension:

```
>>> order = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'baz',
]
data = {
    'bar': 'barValue',
    'foo': 'fooValue',
    'baz': 'bazValue',
}
>>>                         
>>> [data[o] for o in order]
['fooValue', 'barValue', 'bazValue']
```